# How to trace my Analytics.record() event sent to AWS Personalize?

Tags: javascript, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint, amazon-personalize

I am trying to emit an event of type 'Identify' to AWS-Personalize. However there is no provision to see events other than types: Session Start and Session End inside AWSPinpoint

Also tried editing Pinpoint policy to enable it use .record() api as shown here... https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/analytics#update-your-iam-policy

```js
Amplify.Auth.currentUserCredentials()
  .then((user) => {
    setCookie("COGNITO_ID", user.identityId);
    Analytics.record({
      eventType: "Identify",
      properties: {
        "userId": user.identityId,
     }
    }, 'AmazonPersonalize');
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

I am able to get the identityId however, I don't see any event recorded at the Event Tracker inside AWS Personalize. All I can see is Session Start and Session End events inside Pinpoint

Answer (score 1):

1. Sometimes it takes a while for the events to show up.
2. Additionally, `Analytics.record` is only for [custom events](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/analytics#recording-custom-events). Its API doesn't expect a `eventType` or a `properties` key.

You can track custom events like this:

```
import Analytics from '@aws-amplify/analytics';

Analytics.record({
  name: 'videoView',
  attributes: { content: 'gaming', creator: 'Geromekevin' },
  metrics: { minutesWatched: 14 },
});
```

A view minutes after the function has been invoked inside your app they should show up in your console.

Comment: I am actually working on Amazon's new ML-assisted personalization solution - AWS Personalize. And the docs here suggest otherwise... https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/analytics#working-with-the-api-2. This operation indeed take eventType and properties attributes